# How to Create fluent template which composed of couple of datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0, wpf-4.5

I am trying to create a fluent page that is being built by some other data template.

For example:

I have two `DataTemplates`.

- `DataTemplate1` => Button and Textblock IN StackPanel. Like:

  ```
  stackpanel << [Button] textblockwithtext >>
  ```
- `DataTemplate2` => Textblock and Combobox IN StackPanel. Like:

  ```
  stackpanel << 11111111thisisnewtextblock >> [ComboBox]
  ```

And after I will merge them, like this is a third template (something like this:

```
stackpanel << DataTemplate1 DataTemplate 2 >>
```

I will get something that is not fluent. It may be all in the same line,

or in two line but it will break in the middle, like:

**button text1  \n

text2 \n 
combox.**

and I want some thing like this:
**button  \n text1 and half of text2  \n  the last half of text2 and combo box.** (according to the amount of space of the window).

So, I would like to find a working wrapping way when i am using couple of datatemplates (Wrapping panel is not what I am looking for. I am search for a way to merge up couple of datatemplates - let them wrap with each other, that they won't be a completely different part).

I have tried to work with run in Document but it almost impossible to create datatemplate for them.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `Any ideas?` - Yes. Please post your current XAML instead of trying to explain it in words.

Comment: I don't know how to create it. This is the point.

Answer (score 0):

close enough ?

```
 <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


         <Button Grid.ColSpan="2" />
         <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColSpan="2">
               <Run Text="{Binding Text1}" />
               <Run Text="{Binding Text2 , Converter={StaticResource StringToSubStringConverter,ConverterParameter=0}}" /> 
         </TextBlock>

         <Text Text="{Binding Text2 , Converter={StaticResource StringToSubStringConverter,ConverterParameter=1}}" Grid.Row="2" 

         <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />

      </Grid>  
 </DataTemplate>
```

1 and 0 for converter parameter signifies lower half and upper half.

Comment: Thank's, but I want it to be generic. if there is enough place, Don't wrap the text. I want like a panel that does it good.